Using automasking features in background mode
I've been attempting to use the automasking features (specifically bpy.ops.sculpt.mask_from_cavity() through python script in background mode. It seems this doesn't work and results in seg faults. I've attached a minimal example below
mesh_objects = [obj for obj in bpy.data.objects if obj.type == 'MESH']

for obj in mesh_objects:
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='SCULPT')
    bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.sculpt.use_automasking_cavity_inverted = True
    bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.sculpt.automasking_cavity_factor = 1.0
    bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.sculpt.automasking_cavity_blur_steps = 2
    bpy.ops.sculpt.mask_from_cavity(settings_source="SCENE")

I know operators aren't really designed to be used in background mode, but I'm wondering if there is a method that I could still use this functionality. It doesn't seem well contained in the blender python api, and I've tried to reimplement it in python but it is obviously extremely slow. Is there a lightweight way to expose this to python?
Thanks in advanced!
